# Are users able to find my e-mail / name via commits on github using API?

Tags: git, svn, github

SOF,

I'm commiting code to my SVN on github and am wondering if users are able to get access to my e-mail address and/or name?

Github for windows says that: *"This will be used in the commits you create. Keep in mind that if you publish commits, anyone will have access to this email"*

However, I am unable to work out where and how, I don't get anything via either email that I am using and can't find anything anywhere on the respective gits.

If they are able to find these details, can someone recommend a service that users are unable to find out my e-mail address from?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of github and commits, but as a total outsider to the nature of your question, I would think that creating a github-only email address would solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed it would but I would need to create new githubs and delete my old ones :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Clone the repo locally

Simply clone a repo locally

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repo target-dir
```

### Check out details

Now the easiest way is to use

```
git log --pretty=short
```

or a shortcut of above

```
git shortlog
```

Then there are the following options/flags:

1. `s` for `summary` to suppress the commit description and provide a count only
2. `e` to show the email address of the `author`

### Summary

The following git command will allow you to show the mail address of every author who signed his commits:

```
git shortlog -se
```

#### Footnotes

<sup>*Chose `se` for StackExchange, but the order of flags is not important.*</sup>

<sup>*The "problem" you are facing is **not** GitHub, but Git specific.*</sup>

Comment: I just found out a way to find out if my e-mail address is public and it is, I've got to remove my accounts now. Use the following URL: https://api.github.com/users/xxxxxxx/events/public and change xxxxxxxx to the username in question and it shows their e-mail.

Comment: @Ryflex This won't solve the "problem" of a public mail address. Anyway, if that works for you, add it as answer and mark it as solution.

Comment: the problem is I'm using Github for Windows for pushing my commits as I find it much easier than all of the other programs out there and it forces me to use a name/email for commits

Comment: @Ryflex As I wrote in my answer (see "footnotes"), this is _Git_ specific and not GitHub only. Also: Try `git gui` in your terminal/command line/powershell - much better.

Comment: Ahh, github for windows allows privatization of e-mails via settings your e-mail to username@users.noreply.github.com as found in https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private

Comment: @Ryflex Now you got something that you can use as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Github for windows allows [privatization of e-mails](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private/) to username@users.noreply.github.com

> Every Git commit identifies you with an email address. GitHub does not
>   get many reports of spam being sent to the email addresses in Git
>   commits, but if you are worried about it or have other privacy
>   concerns you can always use a private GitHub address instead.
>
> You can use the email address @users.noreply.github.com for
>   all operations supported by GitHub Flow in the browser.

(Originally posted by @Ryflex in a comment of other answer.)